# why is it not possible to use value as keyword argument in print function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I write my function f as this:

```
def f(a, b, c, d = 4, e = 5, f = 6):
    print(a, b, c, d, e, f)
```

I can call it normally with positional arguments:

```
f(1, 2, 3)
```

And I can also call it using the positional arguments as keyword arguments:

```
f(c=3, a=1, b=2)
```

However, if I do that with the print function, I get an error:

```
>>> print(value=42)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'value' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I tried to use value as keyword because it was what it showed me when I did `help(print)`:

```
Help on built-in function print in module builtins:

print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep=' ', end='\n', file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file:  a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:   string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:   string appended after the last value, default a newline.
    flush: whether to forcibly flush the stream.
```

**edit:**

Now I understand the *objects and I get that print is looking for a tuple of values. The [pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) function illustrates what I ask better:

```
>>> pow(x=2, y=3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: pow() takes no keyword arguments
```

Why can't I never seem to refer to the parameters by their names if I use python functions? As I showed above it worked for my f function.

Comment: But you show an error that has nothing to do with your code fragment, since it shows attribute `value`. To answer your question, here Python uses `*args`.

Comment: Print function doesn't have any argument named `value`. for reference read
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Comment: Himanshu Bansal I see, at that page they call it *objects instead of value. It's the first time I see the *, what does it mean?

Comment: @plx for * and ** in python read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-asterisk-and-star-asterisk-do-for-parameters

Comment: Also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970072/python-library-functions-taking-no-keyword-arguments

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of `print` is [this](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html?highlight=built#print):

> print(*objects, sep=’ ‘, end=’\n’, file=sys.stdout, flush=False)

The `objects` parameter has a `*` before, so it is expected to be a **variable number of positional arguments***

**Edited after* @brunodesthuilliers *comment.*

Comment: The `objects` parameter as a `*` before which means the function accepts a variable number of positional arguments (which will be available as a `tuple` inside the function's body). This _certainly_ doesn't mean you're 'expected' to pass a list to `print()`.