# Python library functions taking no keyword arguments

Tags: python, functional-programming, keyword-argument, functools

This problem originated when I tried to apply a more functional approach to problems in python. 
What I tried to do is simply square a list of numbers, no biggie.

```py
from operator import pow
from functools import partial 

squared = list(map(partial(pow, b=2), range(10))
```

As it turns out, this didn't work. `TypeError: pow() takes no keyword arguments`

Confused I checked if `pow(b=2, a=3)` did. It didn't.

I've checked the [operator source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/operator.py), nothing suspicious.

Confused, I've begun to doubt my own python knowledge, I made a pow function myself.

```py
def pow(a, b):
  return a ** b
```

Then I tried doing the same thing with my function and surprisingly, everything worked.

I'm not going to guess what is the cause of the problem, what I'm asking is simply **why** is this a thing and if there exists a workaround.

Comment: It's a thing because the C code isn't written to support keyword arguments. As for the workaround, creating a wrapper function (or your own `pow()` is the workaround.

Comment: You could do `list(map(mul, *itertools.tee(range(10))))` but of course this only works for `pow(x, 2)` and does nothing for the general case.

Comment: btw, there is a draft [PEP 457](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0457/) to implement it in Python so you could also create your own positional-only parameters.

Comment: Note: In py 3.8 the builtin `pow()` now accepts keyword args, as it now has the signature: `pow(base, exp, mod=None)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the signature of the built-in `pow()` or `operator.pow()` using  the [`help()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) function in the interactive shell, you'll see that they require **positional-only** parameters (note the trailing slashes):

```
pow(x, y, z=None, /)
pow(a, b, /)
```

The reason is that both functions are implemented in C and don't have names for their arguments. You have to provide the arguments positionally. As a workaround, you can create a pure Python `pow()` function:

```
def pow(a, b):
    return a ** b
```

See also [What does the slash(/) in the parameter list of a function mean?](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#faq-positional-only-arguments) in the FAQ.

Comment: and the work around in this case given how `functools.partial` works is to use: `list(map(partial(pow, 2), range(10)))`

Comment: @Jon Clements: These are not equivalent. In the 1st case a list of powers of `2` is constructed.

Comment: The second example should be `[2 ** n for n in range(10)]` to be equivalent

Comment: Ahhh... yes... I don't know why I always muddle up `partial` in my head... additional arguments are *appended* not *prepended*... so yeah... without being able to name it, `partial`s not going to work there...

Comment: @Wolph yes... but it'd be equivalently incorrect... :)

Comment: So - while `partial` won't do it, you can at least `lambda` it I guess, eg: `list(map(partial(lambda v: pow(v, 2)), range(10)))`... but at that point one might as well stick with the list-comp.

Comment: Certainly an explanation, however it is extremally annoying that the source code I linked (from the official python std mind you) outright lies about it, as the positional-only "flag" simply isn't there. Could somebody prove me wrong by linking the actual source?

@JonClements I'm aware that both comprehension and a lambda would solve the problem... but it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: @JonClements this saddens me deeply.

Comment: @Welperooni: If it helps, you can find the source of the C version of `operator` [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_operator.c).

Comment: @Welperooni unless `squared = list(map(pow, range(10), itertools.repeat(2)))` counts...

Comment: @EugeneYarmash Thank you but could you link the actual python source code? I'd like to at least have my claim that the python source lies, disproven.

Comment: @JonClements that's also a nice solution. I doubt it's as performant but at least it's something.

Answer (score 2):

In current versions of Python, many CPython "builtin" and standard library functions only accept positional-only parameters. The resulting semantics can be easily observed by calling the help method.

> `>>>>help(pow)`
>
> Help on built-in function pow in module builtins:
>
> pow(x, y, z=None, /)
>       Equivalent to `x**y` (with two arguments) or `x**y` % z (with three arguments)
>
> ```
> Some types, such as ints, are able to use a more efficient algorithm when
> invoked using the three argument form.
> ```

The operator source code mentioned in your question may not be matching with that of the python version in which you are trying.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from the b=2 statement.

```
squared = list(map(partial(pow, b=2), range(10))
```

The partial function is passing the keyword parameter 'b' to the pow function, which results in an error since the pow() function takes positional arguments only. See `help(pow)` for more info.

However, another issue I see with this call is that the partial function is operating in an unexpected way:

```
map(partial(pow, 2), range(10))
```

results in this sequence being generated:

```
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512]
```

which shows that the partial function is actually computing `2^range(10)`

If what you are trying to do is square each value in a list, I would recommend simplifying the code by using a lambda function:

```
b=2
test = map(lambda x: x**b, range(10))
print(list(test))
```

which results in:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

with no imports required.

Answer (score -1):

[pow](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/operator.html#operator.pow) as a library function accepts positional-only parameters. So here's how you could do the above:

```
squared = list(map(partial(pow,2), range(10)))
```

As for your other question, by default user defined functions' parameters are [positional-or-keyword parameters](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-parameter), so will work both as regular or kw arguments. Of course defining a new function pow may cause confusion later down the road though so be careful.

Comment: That would be `pow(2, n)`, not `pow(n, 2)`